# Is use of @JsonCreator necessary when using @JsonProperty?

Tags: java, jackson

I am using Jackson *@JsonProperty(name)* annotation on a parameter to a constructor and every document I came across pointed that we must use the *@JsonCreator* annotation with *@JsonProperty* for it to work properly but even without the *@JsonCreator* annotation, my code **works fine** then what is the use of *@JsonCreator*

```
public TestClass(@JsonProperty("name") Map<String, String> data) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Map<String, String> getName() {
    return name;
}
```

The above code works fine even without the @JsonCreator Annotation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Jackson has to know in what order to pass fields from a JSON object to the constructor. Because you have a single argument constructor, the creation works without `@JsonCreator`

From javadoc

> Marker annotation that can be used to define constructors and factory
>   methods as one to use for instantiating new instances of the
>   associated class.
>
> NOTE: when annotating creator methods (constructors, factory methods),
>   method must either be:
>
> Single-argument constructor/factory method without JsonProperty
>   annotation for the argument: if so, this is so-called "delegate
>   creator", in which case Jackson first binds JSON into type of the
>   argument, and then calls creator Constructor/factory method where
>   every argument is annotated with either JsonProperty or JacksonInject,
>   to indicate name of property to bind to

Answer (score 8):

Newer versions of Jackson also do consider the case where all parameters have explicit `@JsonProperty`, to remove the need for separate `@JsonCreator`.
It may be the case that Javadocs have not been updated to explain this special case.

Note that special case of single `String` / `int` / `long` / `boolean` argument is slightly different, because while that would be detected as well (for `public` constructor), it be "Delegating" creator and only match if the whole incoming value is of matching JSON type (JSON String, Number or Boolean, respectively).