# Java Jackson Deserialization of Enum Fails

Tags: java, json, java-8, jackson

I have a question about something I am trying to understand about Jackson Serialization.

I have been using this Guide as my reference guide to Jackson Serialization:
https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-enums

Given the following JSON

```
{
  "customerName": "John Doe",
  "deliveryType": 1,
  "address": "Bakersfield 5a"
}
```

DeliveryType is an Enum. It has a Code and a getCode.

> Jackson will look for the Enum object that has a getCode() return value of 1

The getCode() is annotated with @JsonValue.
Although Serialization works, Deserialization does not work.

DeliveryType.A does serialize to 1, but 1 deserialize to DeliveryType.B
It looks like it is using Ordinal to Deserialize. If I try to Deserialize the value of 0, then it will deserialize to DeliveryType.A

Although I can get it to work by annotating a method with @JsonCreator in additional to the @JsonValue.

Why do I need both @JsonCreator and @JsonValue?

Using Jackson 2.10.2 and Java 8
I do not have an explicit dependency on Jackson. I am getting it from the dependency `io.leangen.graphql:spqr`.
Add dependency on Jackson 2.15.2, then it works without @JsonCreator.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonValue;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public enum DeliveryType {

    A (1, "Delivery A", "X"),
    B (2, "Delivery B", "Y");

    private final Integer code;
    private final String description;
    private final String textCode;

    @JsonCreator
    public static DeliveryType fromCode(final Integer code) {
        return Stream.of(DeliveryType.values())
                .filter(type -> type.code == code)
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);
    }

    @JsonValue
    public Integer getCode() {
        return code;
    }

}
```

I also created a JUnit Test for the enum. Which will fail with the older Jackson.

```
public class DeliveryTypeTest {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    private final ObjectWriter writer;

    public DeliveryTypeTest() {
        this.objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        writer = objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter();
    }

    @Test
    public void serialize() throws JsonProcessingException {
        final DeliveryType type = DeliveryType.A;
        final String json = writer.writeValueAsString(type);
        Assertions.assertEquals(DeliveryType.A.getCode().toString(), json);
    }

    @Test
    public void deserialize() throws JsonProcessingException {
        final String jsonValue = DeliveryType.A.getCode().toString();
        final DeliveryType deSerializedType = objectMapper.readValue(jsonValue, DeliveryType.class);
        Assertions.assertEquals(DeliveryType.A, deSerializedType);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that it is the **version** of Jackson which makes the difference? As you have the old Jackson as a transitive dependency from another library, it **might** be this library which somehow configures the Jackson in its own manner.

Comment: Another tip: try `fromCode()` instead of `fromKode()`. :)    
And read https://stackoverflow.com/q/40843860/2886891, if it helps.

Comment: fromKode() is just a typo. It should be fromCode().

Comment: Thanks for that link. An comment there said "Newer versions of Jackson also do consider the case where all parameters have explicit @JsonProperty, to remove the need for separate @JsonCreator.".

Comment: Yes, I would have posted this as an answer, however it is not supported by any source so it is just more or less the same as you observed :) It even says "It may be the case that Javadocs have not been updated..." :)